# Upgrade Plone 3.3.6 to either Plone 4.3.7 or Plone 5 (Error: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'remove')

Tags: plone

I'm attempting an upgrade of an existing site from Plone 3.3.6 to Plone 4.3.7, and then on to Plone 5.0.

The existing site is very small, and has no add-on Products installed (vanilla Plone, vanilla template, etc.)   It *did* have CacheFu installed, but after some earlier obvious errors with that, I removed it prior to the upgrade.  I'm simply copying the contents of var/filestorage (Data.fs, etc) from v3 site to v4 site and re-running buildout.

In Plone 4.3.7, when running the UPGRADE option, I see a lot of successful activity, and then the following error at the bottom:

```
    Upgrade aborted. Error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Plone4_migration/buildout-cache/eggs/Products.CMFPlone-4.3.7-py2.7.egg/Products/CMFPlone/MigrationTool.py", line 259, in upgrade
    step['step'].doStep(setup)
  File "/usr/local/Plone4_migration/buildout-cache/eggs/Products.GenericSetup-1.7.7-py2.7.egg/Products/GenericSetup/upgrade.py", line 160, in doStep
    self.handler(tool)
  File "/usr/local/Plone4_migration/buildout-cache/eggs/plone.app.upgrade-1.3.18-py2.7.egg/plone/app/upgrade/v40/betas.py", line 99, in beta3_beta4
    value.remove('Large Plone Folder')
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'remove'
```

If I skip Plone 4.x and jump right to Plone 5.0, I can't even run the UPGRADE feature, and just get the following error trace on the console:

```
2015-10-09 01:14:21 ERROR Zope.SiteErrorLog 1444371261.060.792132208718 http://www.example.com/example
Traceback (innermost last):
  Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 127, in publish
  Module ZPublisher.BaseRequest, line 444, in traverse
  Module ZPublisher.BeforeTraverse, line 97, in __call__
  Module Products.CMFCore.PortalObject, line 75, in __before_publishing_traverse__
  Module zope.event, line 31, in notify
  Module zope.component.event, line 24, in dispatch
  Module zope.component._api, line 136, in subscribers
  Module zope.component.registry, line 321, in subscribers
  Module zope.interface.adapter, line 585, in subscribers
  Module zope.component.event, line 32, in objectEventNotify
  Module zope.component._api, line 136, in subscribers
  Module zope.component.registry, line 321, in subscribers
  Module zope.interface.adapter, line 585, in subscribers
  Module plone.app.theming.plugins.hooks, line 33, in onRequest
  Module plone.app.theming.policy, line 90, in isThemeEnabled
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'enabled'
```

Comment: Try to upgrade to Plone 4 first

Comment: I tried upgrading to 4.3.7, and was able to start running the upgrade tool before it fails.  Any suggestions on the updated error description above?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known bug which has a fix that was not released yet: https://github.com/plone/Products.CMFPlone/issues/1134

Comment: Thanks!   I patched the betas.py file, re-ran buildout, and now the portal_migration tool successfully updates from 3.3.6 to 4.3.7 without error.